# A word that describes a positive form of envy

Tags: word-choice

Is there an English word that's similar to the meaning of envy, but in a positive way? In other words, if "envy" is hoping for the removal of someone else's blessing, what is the word for "wanting the same blessing for yourself but without wanting the blessing to be removed from the possessor"?

> Envy = "I hate to see her luxurious house".
>
> Word? = "I wish I were as generous as he is".

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/266611/42179 and http://english.stackexchange.com/q/41995/42179 and quite a few here: http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=envy+positive

Comment: In some context, "[inspiration](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/inspiration)" may fit.

Comment: Have you tried using a thesaurus? https://www.merriam-webster.com/ might help.

Comment: Duplicate: english.stackexchange.com/q/266611/42179

Comment: What makes you think that *envy* means *hoping for the removal of someone else's blessing*? (And what does envy have to do with blessings?)

Comment: *envy* is not necessarily negative. It does not necessarily detract from the person envied. If you envy Joe because he has a new car that does not imply that you want a new car AND you want Joe to lose his new car.

Comment: The problem is, there are certain human emotions to which no precise words are assigned. Indeed, envy is a word that can be either positive or negative depending on the context. So can be jealousy.

Comment: Envy is frustration or resentment toward someone because they have possessions, talents, or position that you lack. The resentment often takes the form of wishing the other person did not have it, or a need to acquire the same thing for yourself, but either way it's an unpleasant, negative emotion. It is seen as a weakness or failing of the person experiencing it, not a problem with the person being envied. That's why it's one of the seven deadly sins. If used casually or humorously as a way to express admiration it could be considered flattery, but still not really positive.

Comment: I think you may be confusing envy with jealousy.  At least to me, envy is fairly positive: you like what someone has/is, and would like to have some too, without taking it away from the other person.  You might even make the envied person into a role model.  With jealousy, the primary desire seems more to take away what the other person has, even though you might not actually want it yourself - as with the fable of the dog in the manger.

Comment: @jamesqf The [Seven Deadly Sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins) disagree --- _envy_ is mentioned explicitly. So while the meaning may be both positive and negative, it is generally viewed quite negative. Also, this is about emotional feeling of words and you have to consider non-native speakers who may easily not be able to distinguish this an immediately see _envy_ as a negative thing, because it's the most common usage.

Comment: @jamesqf Jealousy is NOT about wanting to take something away from someone else, it's about being angry or worried that someone else is trying to take something away from you. If my girlfriend is hanging around with a friend and I'm worried he is trying to steal her affections, or that she may be cheating, I am jealous. Meanwhile that other guy may be envious of me, because I have a relationship with her that he wishes he could have.

Comment: In colloquial usage, "envy" is certainly much more neutral than "jealousy", and is frequently found in contexts where an arguably positive connotation could be inferred.

Comment: @barbecue: But in your example, the jealousy is over the ANTICIPATION of the other person getting what you want instead of you, or the fear that he might be getting some of it unbeknownst to you - that is, the "cheating".

Comment: @yo': Your "seven deadly sins" context really only applies to followers of the Christian religion. Many words have different meanings in a religious context than in general use.  There are likewise many things, a number of which are mentioned in your link, that are seen as "sinful" in the context of Christianity, which I, a non-Christian, rather enjoy.  As apparently many other people do also :-)

Comment: First, Christianity's influence on the English language is incredibly huge, so ignoring things just because they came from Christianity is going to give you an extremely skewed view. Second, The concept of a list of undesirable behaviors is absolutely not unique to Christianity. The seven deadly sins are just a Christian expression of themes common throughout history in many cultures. The seven graces are in opposition to the seven sins. Buddhism has the eight-fold path, Islam has the Al-Kabirah, etc. Even Aristotle made lists of virtues and vices.

Comment: I would like to add this: we are not black-and-white beings; our emotions are complex. Being envious can be positive. While the Bible says it envy is a sin, I think it is understood that this refers to the negative end of the spectrum. Consider the following:

He has such a cozy home. I wish my home was as cozy as his.

He has such a cozy home. Wish mine was like that. He doesn't deserve it, I work so hard, and get to live in a dump.
  

He has such a cozy home. Mine is a dump, wish mine was like his. Props to him! One day I'll have one too.

The last one is what the OP asked about.

Answer (score 38):

You can **aspire** to be like them. Rather than a feeling of envy, you have a feeling of aspiration.

> [aspire](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/aspire)
>
> verb
>
> to long, aim, or seek ambitiously; be eagerly desirous, especially for
>   something great or of high value (usually followed by to, after, or an
>   infinitive):
>
> *to aspire after literary immortality; to aspire to be a doctor.*
>
> [dictionary.com]

Comment: Indeed. See also the theory of "aspirational choice" used in marketing.

Comment: My first thought too.

Answer (score 6):

***[Long for](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/long+for)***, perhaps? (According to **"thefreedictionary.com"**)

> to desire or pine for someone or something.

Answer (score 5):

**[crave](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crave)**

verb

> 1. Feel a powerful desire for (something)
>
> 'if only she had shown her daughter the love she craved'

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think "crave" reflects a positive feeling at all; it's more of an involuntary or overriding desire - a craving for chocolate, or heroin, or attention. It implies desperation. In fact, I can't think of a single positive example.

Answer (score 4):

I think **appreciation** is the best fit.

> Appreciation - noun - the recognition and enjoyment of the good
>   qualities of someone or something.

Answer (score 3):

*Want*, *wish* (for/to), *lust* (for/after), *hope* (for/to), *desire*, *admire*, *emulate*, *plan* (for/to), *intend* (to), *will*, *envision*, *covet*, *aspire* (to), *hanker* (for), *yearn* (for/to), and some form of (*want* to) *share/enjoy the blessings* (of)/ *be blessed* (like/as) [INSERT PERSON]

These can each, depending upon the context, convey a desire to "emulate" another's "gifts."

You may find that your meaning is better conveyed by a phrase that includes the object of lust, than with the replacement of a single word.

> *"I knew in my heart that I **would someday** have a mansion like hers."*
>
> *"I **long** to be loved by as many friends as is my brother."*
>
> *"My parents' marriage is an **admirable** one, the kind I **hope** to have for myself."*

Comment: 'Lust after' hardly corresponds to 'in a positive way'.

Comment: Aspire to is good, it indicates a positive desire to emulate a positive thing or behavior, but it's kind of hidden in the many other words. You may want to thin the herd a little. Also, the large number of quotation marks and other punctuation makes it look more like a stream of computer data than a sentence.

Answer (score 3):

When someone else's desirable traits or things encourage you to try to achieve similar success yourself, you are **[motivated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motivate)** or **[inspired](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inspire)** by them. This is not exclusively tied to another specific person, as a thing or place could serve, but it's probably the closest thing to a positive version of envy that is widely used in English.

Inspiration is more positive than motivation, which can be neutral or even negative in some cases, but both are [widely](http://www.inc.com/lolly-daskal/100-motivational-quotes-that-will-inspire-you-to-succeed.html) [used](http://www.apbspeakers.com/motivation-inspiration-speakers) [to mean](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/248811) [positive encouragement](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/lifestyle/30-inspirational-songs-that-keep-you-motivated-for-life.html).

Answer (score 1):

While "inspire" and "aspire" are good fits, envy and jealousy have a slightly darkly humorous aspect when used to describe appreciation. Also, the wrongful desire makes the object even more valuable.

Examples of this usage can be found in the Twitter hashtag Jelly:
"i hope i can sing with IA-san later, her voice is so deep~ #jelly"

For that reason, I propose *Covet*.

See the 2nd definition of Dictionary.com (verb with object)
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/covet

1. to desire wrongfully, inordinately, or without due regard for the rights of others: "to covet another's property."
2. to wish for, especially eagerly: "He won the prize they all coveted."

And when something is covetable, it is something that people want to have
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/covetable.

This can be compared to the proverb "immitation is the greatest flattery", which also takes a normally negative activity (immitating denotes lack of creativity) but still has a positive output to the object.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is admiration.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It is not sufficient on this site to suggest an answer; you should *assert* it by providing an explanation why you suggest it, including examples and suitable referenences. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: @choster: unfortunately, I don't think the tour and Help Center are of much help for this purpose. Could you take a look at my recent Meta question: [Can we write a better help page on “How do I write a good answer?”](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/10091/can-we-write-a-better-help-page-on-how-do-i-write-a-good-answer)?

Comment: @sumelic While the tour and help center do not provide detailed guidance on the suitability of answers, I will wager any day that the author of an answer such as this has never bothered with either, and would be edified as a general matter.

Comment: It may be a rather short and unhelpful answer, but it contains the right word.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the newer word 'compersion' on Wikipedia here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compersion

*The feeling of joy one has experiencing another's joy, such as in witnessing a toddler's joy and feeling joy in response.*

Comment: For more info see: [Is there a word like “compersion” that isn't just for romantic/sexual situations?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221858/is-there-a-word-like-compersion-that-isnt-just-for-romantic-sexual-situations)